# controlling the number of edges in a "object in curve" (Sverchok)

Tags: node-editor, add-on, sverchok

[image]

How I might control the number of edges in the "X" direction for this surface? The edges in "Y" axis are controlled by the "Float series count"

Comment: Everything nodes :D Yes!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the List-Item node with Int Range which will delete some points along the X axis depending on the step you set in the Int Range node :  ( change the step to get different results )

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way, it gives you separate control over the 0..1 range between U and V, by using two Vector interpolation nodes

[image]

[image]